# Can the Reeb foliation of $S^3$ be realized as stable manifold foliation of a smooth hyperbolic discrete dynamic on $S^3$?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, foliations, hyperbolic-dynamics

Can the Reeb foliation of  $S^3$ be  realized as foliation associated to stable(or unstable) manifolds of  a  hyperbolic discrete  dynamic on $S^3$?If yes what is  a  precise formulation for  that Hyperbolic  diffeomorphism?

Answer (score 4):

No, because it has a unique leaf that is a torus. That can't be a stable or unstable manifold; one reason is that it can't get either bigger or smaller under the action of the hyperbolic dynamical system.

Comment: Thank  you  very much  for  your  answer. I  just relaized that manifolds with  spher  rational  homology  do not admit anasov  diffeomorphism. So  $S^3$ does not  admit  any Anasov diffeomorphism.  What  partial  hyperbolic  structure?  Just  another question, regardless of the above  obstruction, why does  your answer implies that we  have  no  the required hyperbolic  dynamic?  Because the  nearby  leaves approaches the  torus?Do you  mean that an Anasov  diffeomorphism on a  compact  manifold does  not  admit  an invariant  compact proper  submanifold? If yes , why?

Comment: BTW  I  mean  does sphere admit a  Partially  hyperbolic  diffeomorphism  and  is there  one  for  which the  reeb  foliation is  invariant(Maybe a union of  stable and  center manifolds)?

Comment: The unique torus leaf is mapped to itself. Picture what happens if it's tangent to a center and a stable direction: its area would have to shrink, which is impossible. On the other hand, if all you want is a non-identity map whose dynamics respect the Reeb foliation, there's a whole family of rotations (which of course have no stable or unstable directions).